# Feedparser pubdate gives error when trying to store into a table with asyncpg

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, feedparser, asyncpg

I am trying to store feedparser data into a Postgres database via asyncpg and I am getting an error while storing pubdate that is of type timestamptz in the database
I have a Postgres table test with the following structure

```
+---------------------+----------------------+
| feed_item_id (uuid) | pubdate(timestamptz) |
+---------------------+----------------------+
|                 ... |                  ... |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

I am using feedparser to load data from RSS and save it to this table

```
def md5(text):
    import hashlib
    return hashlib.md5(text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

def fetch():
    import feedparser
    data = feedparser.parse('https://cointelegraph.com/rss')
    return data

async def insert(rows):
    import asyncpg
    async with asyncpg.create_pool(user='postgres', database='postgres') as pool:
        async with pool.acquire() as conn:
            results = await conn.executemany('INSERT INTO test (feed_item_id, pubdate) VALUES($1, $2)', rows)
            print(results)

async def main():
    data = fetch()
    first_entry = data.entries[0]
    await insert([(md5(first_entry.guid), first_entry.published)])

import asyncio
asyncio.run(main())
```

I immediately get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncpg/protocol/prepared_stmt.pyx", line 168, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
  File "asyncpg/protocol/codecs/base.pyx", line 206, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.Codec.encode
  File "asyncpg/protocol/codecs/base.pyx", line 111, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.Codec.encode_scalar
  File "asyncpg/pgproto/./codecs/datetime.pyx", line 208, in asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto.timestamptz_encode
TypeError: expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in insert
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-load-feed-items-uopsj7-P/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 358, in executemany
    return await self._executemany(command, args, timeout)
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-load-feed-items-uopsj7-P/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1697, in _executemany
    result, _ = await self._do_execute(query, executor, timeout)
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-load-feed-items-uopsj7-P/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1731, in _do_execute
    result = await executor(stmt, None)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 254, in bind_execute_many
  File "asyncpg/protocol/coreproto.pyx", line 958, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.CoreProtocol._bind_execute_many_more
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 220, in genexpr
  File "asyncpg/protocol/prepared_stmt.pyx", line 197, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $2 in element #0 of executemany() sequence: 'Thu, 04 Aug 2022 03:29:19 +0100' (expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'str')
```

I tried to use the published_parsed field instead of the published and I got another error

```
async def main():
    ...
    await insert([(md5(first_entry.guid), first_entry.published_parsed)])

asyncio.run(main())
```

This time the error is complaining about struct_time

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncpg/protocol/prepared_stmt.pyx", line 168, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
  File "asyncpg/protocol/codecs/base.pyx", line 206, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.Codec.encode
  File "asyncpg/protocol/codecs/base.pyx", line 111, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.Codec.encode_scalar
  File "asyncpg/pgproto/./codecs/datetime.pyx", line 208, in asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto.timestamptz_encode
TypeError: expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'struct_time'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in insert
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-load-feed-items-uopsj7-P/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 358, in executemany
    return await self._executemany(command, args, timeout)
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-load-feed-items-uopsj7-P/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1697, in _executemany
    result, _ = await self._do_execute(query, executor, timeout)
  File "/Users/vr/.local/share/virtualenvs/python-load-feed-items-uopsj7-P/lib/python3.9/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1731, in _do_execute
    result = await executor(stmt, None)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 254, in bind_execute_many
  File "asyncpg/protocol/coreproto.pyx", line 958, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.CoreProtocol._bind_execute_many_more
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 220, in genexpr
  File "asyncpg/protocol/prepared_stmt.pyx", line 197, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.PreparedStatementState._encode_bind_msg
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $2 in element #0 of executemany() sequence: time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=8,... (expected a datetime.date or datetime.datetime instance, got 'struct_time')
```

How do I store this feedparser date into Postgres using asyncpg?

Comment: What is stopping you from converting the string into a date / datetime before inserting in the database?

Comment: @snakecharmerb i read here that it does not convert leapseconds properly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697815/how-do-you-convert-a-time-struct-time-object-into-a-datetime-object

Comment: As far as I can gather, PostgreSQL does not support leap seconds: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68629595/5320906) will be of some help.